# How can secrets be distributed in a docker swarm?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm

Currently I use env and sql files so that docker compose can load secrets from there and build sql database docker instances with specific user/password. The question is, how can this be ported to docker swarm? Docker secrets seem to only provide secret files over encrypted channels, but not set environment variables or be able to configure docker builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Once the secret reaches a manager node, it gets saved to the internal
>   Raft store, which uses NACL’s Salsa20Poly1305 with a 256-bit key to
>   ensure no data is ever written to disk unencrypted. **Writing to the
>   internal store gives secrets the same high availability guarantees
>   that the the rest of the swarm management data gets.**

https://blog.docker.com/2017/02/docker-secrets-management/

Answer (score 1):

Extending Peter Muryshkin’s answer with an significant restriction. Distributing secrets has to be adapted to a [file-based approach](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#use-secrets-in-compose).

> Note: Docker secrets do not set environment variables directly. This
>   was a conscious decision, because environment variables can
>   unintentionally be leaked between containers (for instance, if you use
>   --link).

Some images already support this such as [Wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/r/_/wordpress/) and [MySQL](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) while others have to be updated to use this approach.